# How to remove the border of an Icon in a JButton using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, border, jbutton

first time making a question here. First of all, Eclipse (as far as I'm aware of) don't let you re dimension images through the design tab directly so to solve this I made a method that convert the icon from ImageIcon to image, re dimension it and then convert it back. The problem is that when I use the re dimensioned image it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSpuv.png) in a JButton.

I have already tried to create a emptyBorder in the JButton but that only remove the border of the button, not the icon. How can I remove it?

Edit:
Just noticed that when the Window is not focused the border is not there? [Image related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBxM6.png)

Comment: I can see two possible scenarios here. 1: The original image already has the border. 2: The way you are resizing the image introduces the border due to improper alpha handling. Without your resizing code and the original image there isn't much we can do here.

Comment: Edit, is not either the one or the second because I noticed that when the window is not focused the border is not there, it has something to do with the JButton Icon function I just don't know how to remove the border

Comment: Don't edit your question by using the "back" button of your browser. That will remove the edit I did to your question to post the image. Instead, when you edit your question click on the **"edit"** link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just noticed that when the Window is not focused the border is not there?

```
button.setFocusPainted( false );
```